# Где скачать старые версии Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text

Сегодня я обновился, но Sublime Text стал крашиться и потреблять много оперативной памяти. Где я могу скачать старые версии? На официальном сайте я почему-то не нашёл ссылок на них. Прошлые версии Sublime Text доступны только на каких-то файлообменниках с СМС и прочей фигнёй, но оттуда скачать тоже не получается.

Comment: Да, там не очень понятно сделано. Перейдите на страницу загрузки, скопируйте ссылку для Вашей ОС. Допустим, ссылка `https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203124.zip` , замените 3124 на номер прошлого билда, будет `https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203114.zip` . Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете скачать старые версии с официального сайта, — и в данном ответе я расписал, как, — однако учтите, что это будет «чистый» Sublime Text без плагинов и настроек. В данном текстовом редакторе «из коробки» поставляется довольно ограниченный функционал, а ручная установка всего, что Вам надо, может занять продолжительный срок. Поэтому с Вашего позволения дополню ответ инструкцией, как быстро вернуться к прежним настройкам, рабочему пространству и плагинам.

---

---

Есть такая категория программного обеспечения, которое распространено достаточно широко, обновляется довольно редко, раз в несколько месяцев, но когда обновится — всё ломатся, вылетает куча фатальных ошибок, и форум этого ПО заполняется гневными сообщениями недовольных пользователей. Самый наглядный пример на моей памяти — движок Википедии. Увы, но Sublime Text тоже можно причислить к такому ПО.

---

---

### Профилактика ошибок после обновления

Даунгрейда — когда вы можете откатиться на предыдущую или любую версию, и продолжать спокойно работать с Вашими плагинами, пользовательскими настройками и рабочим пространством, в Sublime Text не предусмотрено.

Посему перед тем, как обновиться, cделайте копию папки, куда установлен Sublime Text. Если что-то пойдёт не так, а у вас не окажется времени разбираться и/или ждать, пока разработчики починят программу, Вы можете запустить исполняемый файл копии и работать в прошлой версии. Разве что периодически программа будет предлагать обновиться.

Кроме того я настроил для себя еженедельную синхронизацию папки с Sublime Text программой [**Karen's Replicator**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/backup-data-easily-with-karens-replicator/) на съёмный носитель.

---

---

### Ручной возврат к предыдущей версии

Если Вы, не сделавши копию, обновились, а всё летит в тартарары, можно сделать downgrade вручную. В данном разделе приводятся инструкции для Sublime Text Portable 32-битной Windows. Надеюсь, разберётесь, как откатиться при другом программно-аппаратном окружении.

#### Скачивание предыдущего билда Sublime Text

В активном окне Sublime Text <kbd>Alt+H</kbd>→ `Changelog` → смотрите, какая версия предшествовала нынешней. На момент написания данного ответа активная версия — Build 3124, прошлая — Build 3114.

[image: **Build 3114**]

Переходим к [**странице загрузки**](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) Sublime Text на официальном сайте. Копируем нужную ссылку для Вашей операционной системы. Для меня ссылка `https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203124.zip` , заменяете 3124 — номер предыдущего билда — на 3114, получится `https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203114.zip`. Вставляете изменённую ссылку в браузер → скачиваете Build 3114 → распаковываете архив.

#### Возврат к предыдущим настройкам

Из папки, где установлена обновлённая версия Sublime Text,  копируете в папку, куда Вы только что распаковали старый Build Sublime Text, две директории — `Data` и `Packages`.

[image: **Data и Packages**]

Лично у меня после данной операции копирования всё работало без сбоев с прежними настройками.

---

---

### Решение проблем в новой версии

Когда у Вас появится время, загляните на [**форум Sublime Text**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/), там наверняка должны быть темы, причём закреплённые, о критических ошибках после обновлений. Я не знаю подробностей Ваших проблем, и сам не столкнулся с ними, но скорее всего, Вам следует обратить внимание на следующий пост:

[**High CPU Usage in Beta 3124**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/high-cpu-usage-in-beta-3124/23060)

Если не нашли на форуме темы по Вашей проблеме, создайте её сами, как можно более точно перечислив шаги для воспроизведения.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) ссылки на файлы 3 версии. Ниже - список build'ов. Если, к примеру, нужна версия для Ubuntu x64, то замените в этой ссылке - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime-text_build-3124_amd64.deb цифры "3124" на номер нужного build'а.

Для второй версии ссылки и перечень предыдущих версий находятся [здесь](https://www.sublimetext.com/2).